# Trusted SSL With Self Sign Certificate In Tomcat Server Without Importing Certificate In Browser

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl, https

My application is running in intranet in tomcat server. I am able to run my application with https but with warning(The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority) also https symbol is crossed in red.
How we can have trusted SSL with self sign certificate in tomcat server without pain of importing certificate in browser?

Comment: You can't. Get it signed. You've already spent more than it costs in investigation.

Comment: Agree with you EJP and thanks for your suggestions. Its interesting for me to know several ways to achieve the requirements and for now I am looking for handcrafted trustmanager. http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php

Answer (score 1):

> How we can have trusted SSL with self sign certificate in tomcat server without pain of importing certificate in browser?

You can't. Self-signed is not trusted by default (where should the trust come from?) and thus you cannot expect the browser to trust it without telling the browser that it can trust it (by importing). Trust is a relationship and can not simply emerge from nowhere.

Comment: Thanks Steffen, well I am interested to know how trust is achieved in case of trusted authority and trying to understand what's going on behind the scene.

Comment: The builtin trusted authorities have somehow proved that they are trustworthy (lengthy process and some even get removed) and then get shipped together with the browser or system. This way you have an initial trust and from this all the other trust is derived (trust chains etc, way to complex to answer here, just google).

Comment: It was helpful Steffen

Answer (score 0):

The warning States that the certificate is valid but browser don't trust the authority issuing the certificate. The only way is to Configure Browser to Ignore the untrusted CA issues, or Trust The organization in this case you .

Alternatively the recommended way is to get a certificate issues from one the of the CA Authority ( Verisign , Godaddy etc).

Comment: can you be more specific for trusting organization. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Any browser confirms below list items before marking a website/url secure:

1. Match the base DNS with that of the certificate CN (Note that the port number doesn't come into picture in this case). For example, if you are accessing https://example.com:8445/something, the certificate CN should be "example.com"
2. The self-signed certificate has to be imported into the respective trust store (Root Certification Authorities) of the system.
3. The certificate must have a SAN (Subject Alternative Name), that matches the DNS. With respect to previous example, the certificate must have at least one SAN equivalent to "example.com". This is a must, and most of the folks miss out on this point, and could not understand why the browser doesn't trust the certificate.

**The Free way to establish trust in browser for internal applications**
Now, all the above 3 criteria cannot be met unless the certificate is signed by a CA. However, there is an easy way. Go to https://freesslcert.org/ to receive a completely free 1 year certificate with all the above criteria incorporated. Follow the steps mentioned in https://freesslcert.org/trust-freesslcert-in-browser and you are all set.

**Paid Solution for external websites**
You can spend some dollars to get a certificate from one of the CA as mentioned here : https://freesslcert.org/get-cert